# Counting number of times value appears in array php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to go from a 1D array that is like
array = ("apple", "apple", "banana", "apple")
 to a 2d array with
Array = ("apple", 3), ("banana", 1)

I have the following code which keeps returning 0. Where am I going wrong?

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Entries WHERE Trial=$trial");   
$activities = array(); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{ 
    $activityCatID = $row['Activity']; 
    $resulting = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ActivityCategory FROM Activity WHERE ActivityID=$activityCatID"); 
    array_push($activities, mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulting));
}

if(sizeof($activities) > 0) 
{       
    $act_and_count = array(); 
    $temp = $activities[0];

    for($ii = 0; $ii < sizeof($activities); $ii++)
    {
        if(!search_array($activities[$ii], $act_and_count))
        {
            $temp = $activities[$ii];               
            $cnt = count(array_filter($activities, create_function('$a', 'return $a==\'' .$temp. '\';')));                          
            $act_and_count[] = array("Activity" => $activities[$ii], "Count" => $cnt);                    
        }      
    }   
}
```

Comment: `array_count_values()` perhaps? Or get your SQL to do the counting for you

Comment: Firstly use PDO secondly do the count at the SQL level, you should get better performance

Comment: How would you do it in SQL if the values in the field are not know i.e. the initial query for all the data under a specific trial returns 2 types of activitiy but a different trial may return more or fewer types of trial?

Comment: By using SQL COUNT() and a GROUP_BY against the `type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do all of this with a simple sql query where you join this two tables and group by `ActivityCategory` (from your example I think that's the key that you want to group by, is not change with what you want).

```
SELECT a.ActivityCategory , count(*) as Count FROM Entries e
INNER JOIN Activity a
ON e.Activity = a.ActivityID
WHERE e.Trial=$trial
GROUP BY a.ActivityCategory
```

After you run this query you will have two columns. In first you have the activity category and on second the count. I think you manage to move this to the array structure you like.

Also change your mysql connection/query to PDO because you are using old deprecated methods.